# Can a ZFS pool be imported only when all drives are present?

Tags: macos, zfs

I use ZFS as my private backup solution with a mirrored pool (e.g. the data exists equally on 4 different drives). Sometimes my laptop doesn't recognize one of the USB drives (I just have to plug them back in again). And when I forget to check and do a `zpool import` I'll have a resilver on my hands, that takes 18 hours. This is especially annoying when I just had a scrub running the last time I exported my zpool.

The question is now if there is a way to only import the zpool if all 4 drives are present? And if zfs doesn't support that natively how would you implement it? I'm on macOS btw.